# Publishing same app but two versions

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Hi I wish to publish on play 2 similar apps but one with commercials and other one for money. How do I approach to this?
Do changing  applicationId in gradle will be enough? Due to that play store not allowing same package names... 
Please give me any tips how to arrange this in Studio and how to publish it.

Comment: Have a look at gradle flavors. Yes, a different application id is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the flavors in your `build.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs { ... }
    buildTypes { ... }
    productFlavors {
      demo {
        applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.app.demo"
        versionName "1.0-demo"
      }
      full {
        applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.app.full"
        versionName "1.0-full"
      }
   }     
}
```

More [info](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

[flavors](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) solves this problem. I think the link will help.